# FlatButton not responding to click

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am making a simple App called Destini . It is basically like a game with a set of questions .
For example If I ask do you like Tea or Coffee ,If you answer coffee ,it will ask me what type of coffee i like as the next question .If you like tea it will ask what type of tea I like .So the next question depends on the users answers. Here in my App if i click on the button it is not moving to the next question .I have made 3 dart files in my project,in which one of them contains a list of questions. I shall be including it here .If u can help me find out the error it will be really helpful :).

Main.dart

```
import 'package:destiini/story_brain.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


//TODO: Step 15 - Run the app and see if you can see the screen update with the first story. Delete this TODO if it looks as you expected.

void main() => runApp(Destini());

class Destini extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: StoryPage(),
    );
  }
}

//TODO: Step 9 - Create a new storyBrain object from the StoryBrain class.
StoryBrain storyBrain = new StoryBrain();
class StoryPage extends StatefulWidget {

  _StoryPageState createState() => _StoryPageState();
}

class _StoryPageState extends State<StoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image:DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('images/background.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        //TODO: Step 1 - Add background.png to this Container as a background image.
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 15.0),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 12,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    //TODO: Step 10 - use the storyBrain to get the first story title and display it in this Text Widget.
                    storyBrain.getStory(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //Choice 1 made by user.
                    setState(() {
                      storyBrain.nextStory(1);
                    });
                    //TODO: Step 18 - Call the nextStory() method from storyBrain and pass the number 1 as the choice made by the user.
                  },
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                    //TODO: Step 13 - Use the storyBrain to get the text for choice 1.
                    storyBrain.getChoice1(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                //TODO: Step 26 - Use a Flutter Visibility Widget to wrap this FlatButton.
                //TODO: Step 28 - Set the "visible" property of the Visibility Widget to equal the output from the buttonShouldBeVisible() method in the storyBrain.
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      storyBrain.nextStory(2);
                    });
                    //Choice 2 made by user.
                    //TODO: Step 19 - Call the nextStory() method from storyBrain and pass the number 2 as the choice made by the user.
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text(
                    storyBrain.getChoice2(),
                    //TODO: Step 14 - Use the storyBrain to get the text for choice 2.
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//TODO: Step 24 - Run the app and try to figure out what code you need to add to this file to make the story change when you press on the choice buttons.

//TODO: Step 29 - Run the app and test it against the Story Outline to make sure you've completed all the steps. The code for the completed app can be found here: https://github.com/londonappbrewery/destini-challenge-completed/
```

Story.dart

```
class Story {
  String storyTitle;
  String choice1;
  String choice2;
  Story({this.storyTitle, this.choice1, this.choice2});
}
```

Story_brain.dart

```
import 'story.dart';
class StoryBrain {
  List<Story> storyData = [
    Story(
        storyTitle:
        'Your car has blown a tire on a winding road in the middle of nowhere with no cell phone reception. You decide to hitchhike. A rusty pickup truck rumbles to a stop next to you. A man with a wide brimmed hat with soulless eyes opens the passenger door for you and asks: "Need a ride, boy?".',
        choice1: 'I\'ll hop in. Thanks for the help!',
        choice2: 'Better ask him if he\'s a murderer first.'),
    Story(
        storyTitle: 'He nods slowly, unphased by the question.',
        choice1: 'At least he\'s honest. I\'ll climb in.',
        choice2: 'Wait, I know how to change a tire.'),
    Story(
        storyTitle:
        'As you begin to drive, the stranger starts talking about his relationship with his mother. He gets angrier and angrier by the minute. He asks you to open the glovebox. Inside you find a bloody knife, two severed fingers, and a cassette tape of Elton John. He reaches for the glove box.',
        choice1: 'I love Elton John! Hand him the cassette tape.',
        choice2: 'It\'s him or me! You take the knife and stab him.'),
    Story(
        storyTitle:
        'What? Such a cop out! Did you know traffic accidents are the second leading cause of accidental death for most adult age groups?',
        choice1: 'Restart',
        choice2: ''),
    Story(
        storyTitle:
        'As you smash through the guardrail and careen towards the jagged rocks below you reflect on the dubious wisdom of stabbing someone while they are driving a car you are in.',
        choice1: 'Restart',
        choice2: ''),
    Story(
        storyTitle:
        'You bond with the murderer while crooning verses of "Can you feel the love tonight". He drops you off at the next town. Before you go he asks you if you know any good places to dump bodies. You reply: "Try the pier".',
        choice1: 'Restart',
        choice2: '')
  ];
  String getStory()
  {
    return storyData[storyNumber].storyTitle;
  }
  String getChoice1()
  {
    return storyData[storyNumber].choice1;
  }
  String getChoice2()
  {
    return storyData[storyNumber].choice2;
  }
  int storyNumber = 0;
  void nextStory(int choiceNumber){
if(storyNumber==0 && choiceNumber==1)
  {
    storyNumber==2;
  }
else if(storyNumber==2 && choiceNumber==1)
  {
    storyNumber==5;
  }
else if(storyNumber==2 && choiceNumber==2)
{
  storyNumber==4;
}
else if(storyNumber==0 && choiceNumber==2)
{
  storyNumber==1;
}
else if (choiceNumber == 1 && storyNumber == 1) {
  storyNumber = 2;
}
else if(storyNumber==1 && choiceNumber==2)
{
  storyNumber==3;
}
else if(storyNumber==3||storyNumber==4||storyNumber==5)
  {
    restart();
  }
  }
  void restart()
  {
    storyNumber=0;
  }
  }
//TODO: Step 23 - Use the storyNumber property inside getStory(), getChoice1() and getChoice2() so that it gets the updated story and choices rather than always just the first (0th) one.



//TODO: Step 25 - Change the storyNumber property into a private property so that only story_brain.dart has access to it. You can do this by right clicking on the name (storyNumber) and selecting Refactor -> Rename to make the change across all the places where it's used.

//TODO: Step 16 - Create a property called storyNumber which starts with a value of 0. This will be used to track which story the user is currently viewing.

//TODO: Step 17 - Create a method called nextStory(), it should not have any outputs but it should have 1 input called choiceNumber which will be the choice number (int) made by the user.

//TODO: Step 20 - Download the story plan here: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1KU6EghkO9Hf2hRM0756xFHgNaZyGCou3

//TODO: Step 21 - Using the story plan, update nextStory() to change the storyNumber depending on the choice made by the user. e.g. if choiceNumber was equal to 1 and the storyNumber is 0, the storyNumber should become 2.

//TODO: Step 22 - In nextStory() if the storyNumber is equal to 3 or 4 or 5, that means it's the end of the game and it should call a method called restart() that resets the storyNumber to 0.

//TODO: Step 27 - Create a method called buttonShouldBeVisible() which checks to see if storyNumber is 0 or 1 or 2 (when both buttons should show choices) and return true if that is the case, else it should return false.
```

[Structure of my if conditionals are displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud8Xs.jpg)

Comment: It might be just me, but why is `storyBrain` not in your state class?

Comment: I have declared it outside the state widget cuz it will show an error if declared inside

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You should be able to declare it in `_StoryPageState` and it should work just fine

Comment: I tried it it again it shows the same error .I guess there was some error in my if statement .Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the variable this way

```
if(storyNumber==0 && choiceNumber==1)
  {
    storyNumber=2; // <-- change == to =
  }
else if(storyNumber==2 && choiceNumber==1)
  {
    storyNumber=5; // <-- change == to =
  } ...
```